# Where is the QtDesigner in PyQt6?

Tags: qt-designer, pyqt6

I find `bindings/QtDesigner` directory, but there are all `.sip` file.

In the [package website](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6/) on pypi, it says

> The `sip-install` tool will also install the bindings from the sdist package but will allow you to configure many aspects of the installation.

`sip-install` need a file named `pyproject.toml`, but there is only `QtDesigner.toml` and it fails to run if I just rename it to `pyproject.toml`.

```
sip-install: pyproject.toml: the '[tool.sip.metadata]' section is missing
```

The content of `QtDesigner.toml` is

```
# Automatically generated configuration for PyQt6.QtDesigner.

sip-version = "6.0.1"
sip-abi-version = "13.0"
module-tags = ["Qt_6_0_0", "Qt_6_0_0", "Linux", "Qt_6_0_0", "Qt_6_0_0", "Linux", "Qt_6_0_0", "Qt_6_0_0", "Linux", "Qt_6_0_0", "Qt_6_0_0", "Linux"]
module-disabled-features = ["PyQt_WebChannel", "PyQt_OpenGL_ES2", "PyQt_WebChannel", "PyQt_WebChannel", "PyQt_OpenGL_ES2", "PyQt_WebChannel"]
```

Answer (score 10):

First, you need to install `pyqt6-tools`:

```
pip install pyqt6-tools
```

Then, you can install QtDesigner:

```
pyqt6-tools designer
```

Also, you can see all commands of `pyqt6-tools` if you run command below:

```
pyqt6-tools --help
```

Output:

```
Usage: pyqt6-tools [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  designer
  installuic
  qmlscene
  qmltestrunner
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the designer of PyQt5 for PyQt6. You can use the following command to convert the ui file to PyQt6 Python file:

```
pyuic6 -x filename.ui -o filename.py
```

Note: You don't need to install pyuic6 it is automatically installed with PyQt6.